# Using ngClass to update p-calendar input

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng-class

I do not want the user to select a future date, but if he/she does, I want to display a red border around the p-calendar's input field.

My css code:

```
    .invalid-date ::ng-deep>p-calendar>.ui-calendar>.ui-inputtext {
     border-color: #a94442;
}
```

HTML code:

```
    <div [ngClass]="{'invalid-date': dateValid()}">
                <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"
                            [hideOnDateTimeSelect]="true"
                            showIcon="true"
                            appendTo="body"
                            dateFormat="d-M-yy"
                            selectOtherMonths="true"
                            showTime="true"
                            hourFormat="24"
                            ></p-calendar>
     </div>
```

Typescript code:

```
date: Date = moment().toDate();

dateValid(): boolean {
return moment(this.date).isAfter(moment());
```

}

Comment: What is the issue  you are facing? If the border is applied to input then border-color: #a94442; will work, other wise you need to add a border (Eg: border: 1px solid #a94442;).  If other issue, please explain.

Comment: Turns out there was global styling that was overriding it, so I just added a hammer, eg border-color: #a94442 !important;

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter the same problem, make sure you don't have any global styling that overrides yours. This was the problem and to solve it, you add what is called a hammer to your line that you want excluded from the global styling.

```
     .invalid-date ::ng-deep>p-calendar>.ui-calendar>.ui-inputtext {
      border-color: #a94442 !important;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can give following suggestions to solve this problem:
1. First of all You should check the class works or not.
2. And It is better than call methods for checking date valid:

html:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'invalid-date': isValid}">
            <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"
                        [hideOnDateTimeSelect]="true"
                        showIcon="true"
                        appendTo="body"
                        dateFormat="d-M-yy"
                        selectOtherMonths="true"
                        showTime="true"
                        hourFormat="24"
                        ></p-calendar>
 </div>
```

ts:

```
isValid: boolean;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes.date.currentValue != changes.date.previousValue) {
    this.checkValidDate();
  }
}

checkValidDate() {
  this.isValid = moment(this.date).isAfter(moment());
}
```